# Как просмотреть последние n строк у очень большого файла

Tags: bash, консоль

Есть текстовый файл, выгрузка в несколько Гб, нужно узнать что в последней строке этого файла.

Пробовал

```
tail -10 filename.txt
```

Из-за большого размера файла команда зависает и ничего не выводит.
Какую ещё команду можно использовать? Операционка macos

Comment: а если попросить последние несколько килобайт (вот такой командой tail -c 4096 filename.txt для последних 4 кб). если это буде работать с приемлемой скоростью, то очевидно, что последние 10 строк в этом выводе и есть последние 10 строк в исходном файле.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iocp2.png - у меня на сервере время выполнения одинаковое, файл 1.2 ГБ. На мой взгляд самое оптимальное - это использование tail в случае, когда не известен номер строки, тот же `sed -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba'` выполнялся `real    0m1.925s` что значительно дольше в сравнении с `tail`